# Categorical to Binary - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math

I am converting the target column from the Adult Income data set (<50K and >=50K) and I want a zero for <50K and a 1 for over or equal to 50K.

When I run the below code it then creates two columns when what I was hoping for in the column was simply where <50K is listed replace this with a 1 and where >50K is listed replace this with a 0.

```
cols_to_transform = [ 'Target' ]
df_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies(columns = cols_to_transform, data=data)

>      Native Country  Target_<=50K  Target_>50K  
>0      United-States             1            0  
>1      United-States             1            0  
>2      United-States             1            0  
>3      United-States             1            0  
>4               Cuba             1            0
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong and how I can get this classification mapped to just the one column, say 'Target'?

Comment: What does your source data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data) you could use the *map* method to create that column:

data["Target_binary"] = data["Target"].map(lambda x: 1 if x == ">50K" else 0)

Answer (score 0):

`pd.get_dummies` is supposed to split the column into one column for each unique value in the original.  You want to simply cast a boolean column to the integers zero or one

```
data['Target_binary'] = data.Target.eq('>50K').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume two categorical values "a","b" in the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({"Target":pd.Series(np.random.randn(5)*50000), "Value":["a","b","a","a","b"]})
cols_to_transform = ["Values"]
df_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies(columns = cols_to_transform, data=data)
```

Then if you want to encode "a" as 1 and "b" as 0 you will get the following for df_with_dummies:

```
         Target  Value_a  Value_b
0   4329.130662        1        0
1 -64012.592710        0        1
2 -21050.741809        1        0
3 -32438.538928        1        0
4  13843.408700        0        1
```

Where Value_a column is exactly what you are looking for. Alternatively you could just do:

```
data["result"] = (data["Value"]=="a").astype(int)
```